# Convert HTML hyperlink code to Markdown (MD) in pure AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, text, html, markdown, command-line

I have a text file or some text to process via the clipboard. It contains a few lines of HTML code, and I'd like to convert it to pure Markdown.

E.g. from:

`This is a link: <a href="https://duck.com">link</a>`

to:

`This is a link: [link](https://duck.com)`

Is there pure AppleScript code (using regex substitution) that can do this?

Alternatively, I am happy with AppleScript calling any CLI tool to process the text via `do shell script` if it's an in-built text which doesn't require `homebrew` or a third party tool to be installed.

Comment: `/usr/bin/sed -E -e 's|<a href="|[link](|g' -e 's|">link</a>|)|g' <<< 'This is a link: <a href="https://duck.com">link</a>'` produces: `This is a link: [link](https://duck.com)`

Comment: If not in clipboard but just an XML file then see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/128106/how-can-i-convert-html-rich-text-to-markdown-in-automator?rq=1

Comment: @mmmmmm yeah I can run that link's "md - Convert - HTML to Markdown" and it does work, but it's python inside automator workflow, is it possible to embed python code in an applescript without having to create a separate .py file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one *example*:

```
set htmlString to "This is a link: <a href=\"https://duck.com\">link</a>"

set mdString to do shell script "/usr/bin/sed -E -e 's|<a href=\"|[link](|g' -e 's|\">link</a>|)|g' <<< " & htmlString's quoted form
```

**Result:**

```
"This is a link: [link](https://duck.com)"
```

This can also be down without the use of the `do shell script` *command*, as in this *example*:

```
set htmlString to "This is a link: <a href=\"https://duck.com\">link</a>"

set htmlString to findAndReplaceInText(htmlString, "<a href=\"", "[link](")
set htmlString to findAndReplaceInText(htmlString, "\">link</a>", ")")

on findAndReplaceInText(theText, theSearchString, theReplacementString)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theSearchString
    set theTextItems to every text item of theText
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to theReplacementString
    set theText to theTextItems as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return theText
end findAndReplaceInText
```

**Result:**

```
"This is a link: [link](https://duck.com)"
```

---

If `This is a link: <a href="https://duck.com">link</a>` is in a file or on the **clipboard**, the *escaping* is done automatically when assigning it to a *variable*.  You then only need to escape the `"` in the `sed` *command* as shown in the *example* above.

---

Other *examples*:

If `This is a link: <a href="https://duck.com">link</a>` in in a file:

```
set htmlFile to "/path/to/filename/ext"
set htmlString to read htmlFile
set mdString to do shell script "/usr/bin/sed -E -e 's|<a href=\"|[link](|g' -e 's|\">link</a>|)|g' <<< " & htmlString's quoted form
```

Or, processing the *file* directly:

```
set htmlFile to "/path/to/filename.ext"
set mdString to do shell script "/usr/bin/sed -E -e 's|<a href=\"|[link](|g' -e 's|\">link</a>|)|g'" & space & htmlFile's quoted form
```

If `This is a link: <a href="https://duck.com">link</a>` is on the **clipboard**:

```
set htmlString to (the clipboard as text)
set mdString to do shell script "/usr/bin/sed -E -e 's|<a href=\"|[link](|g' -e 's|\">link</a>|)|g' <<< " & htmlString's quoted form
```

---

**Note:** The use of the `findAndReplaceInText()` *handler* can also be used in place of the `do shell script` *command* in these other *examples*.

- See also, [Manipulating Text](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ManipulateText.html) in the [Mac Automation Scripting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH56-SW1).

Comment: Superb, thank you! My only comment to anyone is: make sure the input doesn't have other html tags in between the `<a>` and `</a>` tags. Substitute that out using other applescript code first, or it won't process fully.

Comment: @ἐλευθερία, You can also extend the `sed` _command_ with additional substitution _commands_, e.g.: `-e 's|\"><span class=\"s1\">link</span></a>|)|g'`

Comment: I was sure this was going to be a bad question on first glance, but an awesome answer turned that around immediately.

Comment: @user3439894 I've realised your answer only performs this action for that specific hyperlink text example, not for any string as the hyperlink text. This e.g. works for direct text example, can you update the answer? `set mdString to do shell script "sed 's/<a href=\"\\(.*\\)\">\\(.*\\)<\\/a>/[\\2](\\1)/' <<< " & htmlString's quoted form`

Comment: Furthermore, this allows you to convert multiple hyperlinks in the incoming text, not just one: `set mdString to do shell script "perl -pe 's/<a.*?href=\"(.*?)\".*?>(.*?)<\\/a>/[\\2](\\1)/g' <<< " & htmlString's quoted form` - even more superior.

Comment: @ἐλευθερία, Yes. the `sed` _commands_ can be modified to suite ones needs. Please keep in mind the use of the word _example_ in the answer, it is after all just that an example and it is expected for the user to modify the _example_ as required to suite ones express needs. (Technically the _example_ `sed` _command_ matches what was supplied in the question.) I've also updated the question to make use of an **Apple**  supplied _example_ of an **AppleScript** _handler_ to avoid the use of the `do shell script` _command_.

Comment: @user3439894 agreed, I wasn't clear enough in question, and really appreciate your awesome code. At least my comments above can help anyone trying to convert *any* hyperlink no matter how it comes in, and also multiple URLs in the one text string, which is the fuller context I'm doing this in. Your examples for file and clipboard processing are also superb reference to add to everything now on this page. Thanks!