# Batch Converting RTF to Markdown?

Tags: automator, file-conversion, markdown

Anyone have any help, tools, advice, etc. on batch converting RTF to Markdown in MacOS?

I've used Automator a little but when I tried the advice in [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/128106/how-can-i-convert-html-rich-text-to-markdown-in-automator), I couldn't get it to work. I'd love some advice on how I can handle this.

I was able to install the [linked services](http://brettterpstra.com/projects/markdown-service-tools/) from Brett Terpstra, though they don't really show up in Quick Actions or in Automator, but only in the Touch Bar controls for some reason.

[image: Finder Quick Actions]

[image: Touch Bar Customizations]

[image: Automator]

When I try to install the [RTF to Markdown service](http://asfaltboy.github.io/public/md%20-%20Convert%20-%20RTF%20to%20Markdown%20Clipboard.zip) from the thread, it doesn't seem to show up in Services or Quick Actions.

When I drag the service into Automator, and try to run it, I just get an error.

[image: Automator Error]

I truly don't know what I'm doing wrong or how to get this to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!